# Ubuntu 19.04 system install and drive used

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount

I'm pretty sure when I remove my usb it's going to be gone after reboot and i'll have to repeat the process.

Here's what my drives look like now:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                    FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT                    LABEL
loop0                   squashfs      1.9G /rofs                         
loop1                   squashfs     89.3M /snap/core/6673               
loop2                   squashfs     53.7M /snap/core18/941              
loop3                   squashfs      151M /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/31      
loop4                   squashfs        4M /snap/gnome-calculator/406    
loop5                   squashfs     14.8M /snap/gnome-characters/254    
loop6                   squashfs     1008K /snap/gnome-logs/61           
loop7                   squashfs      3.7M /snap/gnome-system-monitor/77 
loop8                   squashfs     35.3M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198  
sda                                  57.3G                               
└─sda1                  ntfs         57.3G /cdrom                        Ubuntu 19_04 amd64
nvme0n1                             238.5G                               
├─nvme0n1p1             ext4          731M                               
├─nvme0n1p2                             1K                               
└─nvme0n1p5             crypto_LUKS 237.8G                               
  └─nvme0n1p5_crypt     LVM2_member 237.8G                               
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   ext4        236.8G                               
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap          980M [SWAP]
```

How can I move my Ubuntu OS to my other drive so it will boot without having to always have the USB stick?

Comment: It looks like you have installed Ubuntu in `/dev/nvme0n1p5`. You seem to have also used the LVM and encryption option during installation. Go ahead and shutdown Ubuntu running from the USB using the drop down menu from the top right corner of the screen. Once the computer is off, unplug the USB. Turn the computer back on. Note down the problem you still have including any error messages. Finally [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1185221/edit) the question and add the additional information in the question.

Comment: By the way, the `sda` is not swap. It is your Ubuntu installation USB, also known as the Live USB.  The terminal command prompt tells me you are using the Ubuntu from the USB now.

Answer (score 1):

Can the label you see could be the label of your iso on the USB drive ? 
Your swap partition is not in sda1 but in nvme0n1p5_crypt and it looks like your system (encrypted) is in the nvme0n1p5_crypt (with the swap).

To locate your installed system, can you do:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```